# An excerpt from a seminar

Tags: general-topology

It is  a statement that a professor made in a seminar which I attended yesterday.He  says that the following hold:

$1$.If $D$ denotes the closed unit disc then there does not exist a continuous mapping $f:D\setminus\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow \{x\in \mathbb R:|x|\leq 1$ which is onto

However  there does  exist a continuous mapping $f:D\setminus\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow \{x\in \mathbb R:|x|> 1\}$ which is onto

I dont know why he says so?Please help
 I know that continuous image of a connected set is connected and of a compact is compact.Also $D$ is both compact and connected.but they dont give anything here

Comment: Is $f$ also required to be 1-1? If not, then such continuous map does exist. E.g. just take projection.

Comment: Why first mapping does not exist?

Comment: I just wrote that it does exist. Ask you professor for clarification, perhaps you did not copy the statement correctly.